# When input button is clicked, perform an action

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        baseURL='http://domain.com/base1';
        $("input#Race").val("btn2");
        $("input#Race").attr("id","btn2");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        baseURL='http://domain.com/base2';
        $("input#pet").val("btn1");
        $("input#pet").attr("id","btn1");
    });
</script>
<td><input class="inputbutton" id="btn1" type=button value="btn1"></td>
```

What's supposed to happen, when you click the button, it changes between btn1 and btn2 and also change the baseURL variable.

But when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: can you post the html for other controls (#pet, #race)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a strange idea to change ids of elements. It would surprise me if it worked. You’d better swap the buttons themselves, instead of swapping their ids.

Comment: Thanks, changed my code and made the button's id "Switch" then made it check the value of the button and do it's stuff according to that.